# Flyout page overlapping in Xamarin iOS

Tags: xamarin.forms, master-pages, visual-studio-2022

[image]I am developing a small application with Xamarin forms in visual studio 2022 version, My project need flyout/master page but It is different android and iOS, Android is not overlapping when click on hamburger menu but iOS is overlapping, I tried to set a FlyoutLayoutBehavior="Popover" but even it is not working, Could you please give me a suggestion?[image]

Comment: Could you provide the code for us to test?

Comment: I have added two screenshot  android and iOS, what I have done, First I have created blank application after that create a flyout page then given start  page as flyout page in app.xaml.cs. When running application i can see two different behaviour android and iOS, please guide me

Comment: Please let me know if you want code, Thanks

Comment: Please anybody suggest me

Comment: I make the sample to show and would feedback today.

Comment: Thanks for the information, I understand but now I am almost finished my project with prism library, is it work prism with shell?

Comment: The Prism do not to implement support for Shell.  https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/issues/1809

Comment: Okay thanks, @WendyZang-MSFT, i will keep it flyout page behaviour for iOS

Answer (score 0):

According to your screenshots, I was able to reproduce this issue. It caused by the Navigation behavior of  `FlyoutPage`.

[image]

The behavior of the navigation experience between flyout and detail pages is platform dependent:

- On iOS, the detail page slides to the right as the flyout page slides from the left, and the left part of the detail page is still visible.
- On Android, the detail and flyout pages are overlaid on each other.
- On UWP, the flyout page slides from the left over part of the detail page, provided that the `FlyoutLayoutBehavior` property is set to Popover.

It it the deault behavior of different platform which we could not change.

If you want to do the overlaid on each page, you could use Shell instead. Create a Shell template project or a Shell Page.

[image]

Ms docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/

Comment: I understand flyoutpage behaviour ,Thanks for your answer Wendy Zang